# How to fill/insert fake data into a MS Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, filegroups, data

I'm trying to [test out some configuration settings](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260393/trying-to-fill-an-ms-sql-table-with-dummy-data-to-fill-up-a-file-in-a-filegroup) for an MS Sql Server `FILEGROUP` and to do this I wish to fill my `FILEGROUP`disk up so it will start populating the 2nd `FILEGROUP`.

I've just created a dummy table that on the `PRIMARY FILEGROUP` and have the following simple sql to insert some data. It's just taking so long and filling it slowly. Are there any better ways to quickly fill a table with junk data that really uses up a lot of hard disk space?

```
--IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.__RandomData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
--BEGIN
--    DROP TABLE dbo.__RandomData; 

--    CREATE TABLE dbo.__RandomData ( 
--        RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
--        SomeInt INT,
--        SomeBit BIT, 
--        SomeVarchar VARCHAR(10), 
--        SomeDateTime DATETIME, 
--        SomeNumeric NUMERIC(16,2) ) 
--END
--GO

DECLARE @count INT 
SET @count = 1

WHILE @count <= 1000000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.__RandomData 
    SELECT    @count, 
            CASE WHEN DATEPART(MILLISECOND, GETDATE()) >= 500 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [SomeBit], 
            CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + 
            CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + 
            CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + 
            CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + 
            CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) + CHAR((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 26) + 97) [SomeVarchar], 
            DATEADD(MILLISECOND, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 6000) * -1, 
                DATEADD(MINUTE, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000) * -1, GETDATE())) [SomeDateTime], 
            (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100001) + ((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100001) * 0.00001) [SomeNumeric]
    SET @count += 1
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a CROSS JOIN between sys.columns, use that same 2, 3 , or 4 times. Have a TOP, with as many rows as you want. Use that as a base for INSERT ... SELECT.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(c1 int identity(1, 1), c2 char(10))

INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT TOP(1000) 'Hello'
FROM sys.columns AS a 
 CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS b 
 CROSS JOIN sys.columns AS c
```

The cross join is a classic trick. Do a cross join between two tables that has 1000 rows each and you have 1,000,000 rows in the result. With 3 tables, you have 1,000,000,000 rows. You can have some "numbers" table you create for these purposes, with for instance 1000 rows in it. Or, do a quick and dirty and use some view that you know exists with a decent amount or rows in it (like sys.columns).